# POST method variable not passing

Tags: php, mysql, post, postman

I'm trying to make a simple "request register app", so I send a variable $appUser_id via POST to a .php file that will make the storage into the database. I worked, for a while, but then it stopped working and I don't know what I changed. It makes the registration into the database but sets the appUser_id to **0**, but I'm sending a number.

It doesn't throw any error but doesn't get the proper variable's value.

And sending the data with Postman for now.

### newRequest.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    require 'connection.php';
    makeRequestRegister();
}

function makeRequestRegister()
{
    global $connect;

    $appUser_id = $_POST["appUser_id"];

    $query = "INSERT INTO requests (appUser_id) VALUES ('$appUser_id')";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);

}

?>
```

### Connection.php

```
<?php

define('hostname', 'localhost');
define('user', 'root');
define('password', 'password');
define('databaseName', 'belandri_TEII');

$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, user, password, databaseName);

?>
```

### Postman

[image]

### DataBase

[image]

Pd: Forget about injection and that kind of protection. I don't care about that for now.

Comment: so, where is that POST array coming from?

Comment: I send appUser_id from an Android App, that also worked after it stopped working.

Comment: You have answers below, have a look at those then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently using the `Headers` tab but, you should be using `Body` tab for POST data.
Check out the following example:

[image]

If you check out the [Postman documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests), you'll see there's several ways to construct the Request Body:

### form-data

> multipart/form-data is the default encoding a web form uses to transfer data. This simulates filling a form on a website, and submitting it. The form-data editor lets you set key/value pairs (using the key-value editor) for your data. You can attach files to a key as well. Do note that due to restrictions of the HTML5 spec, files are not stored in history or collections. You would have to select the file again at the time of sending a request.

### urlencoded

> This encoding is the same as the one used in URL parameters. You just need to enter key/value pairs and Postman will encode the keys and values properly. Note that you can not upload files through this encoding mode. There might be some confusion between form-data and urlencoded so make sure to check with your API first.

### raw

> A raw request can contain anything. Postman doesn't touch the string entered in the raw editor except replacing environment variables. Whatever you put in the text area gets sent with the request. The raw editor lets you set the formatting type along with the correct header that you should send with the raw body. You can set the Content-Type header manually as well. Normally, you would be sending XML or JSON data here.

### binary

> binary data allows you to send things which you can not enter in Postman. For example, image, audio or video files. You can send text files as well. As mentioned earlier in the form-data section, you would have to reattach a file if you are loading a request through the history or the collection.

Comment: You are absolutely right. What a stupid mistake o' mine. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, we all make mistakes! If this worked for you though, please feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) as it let others know that you're good to go! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be sending that post variable in the headers. Use the body tab instead.

Comment: Read @Sean3z answer it was posted first and is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the **$appUser_id** as a string in the query, you don't need to put single quotes around the variable since **double quotes** evaluate vars inside. You can do:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO requests (appUser_id) VALUES ($appUser_id)";
```

Or

```
$query = "INSERT INTO requests (appUser_id) VALUES (".$appUser_id.")";
```